# ios access potentially undefined object

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am accessing a dispatched notification like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleUnpresent:) name:UNPRESENT_VIEW object:nil];

...

-(void)handleUnpresent:(NSNotification *)note;
{
    NSLog(@"%@", note.object.footer);
    //property 'footer' not found on object of type 'id'
}
```

Some of the incoming `note.object` objects have a "footer" and some don't. However, I don't want to go through to trouble of making a class that only has a property called `footer` just to make this work. I even tried `((NSObject *)note.object).footer)` which works in some languages, but apparently not obj-c. What can I do?

Comment: Why not go to the trouble?  ObjC classes are fairly lightweight compared to most languages, and it would allow you to compare the footer property to nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the `isKindOfClass` is certainly the more robust option.  However, if you have multiple unrelated classes that return the property you need, there is another way: `respondsToSelector`.  Just ask if the object has a `footer` method, and you can safely call it.

```
-(void)handleUnpresent:(NSNotification *)note;
{
    id noteObject = [note object];
    if ([note respondsToSelector:@selector(footer)])
    {
        NSLog(@"Footer = %@", [noteObject footer]);
    }
}
```

That `respondsToSelector` method is powerful and handy in the right places, but don't go wild with it.  Also, it can't tell you anything about the return type, so the `footer` you get may not be of the class you were expecting.

The syntax for `noteObject.footer` and `[noteObject footer]` are easy to treat as equivalent.  However, when the class of `noteObject` is unknown, the compiler will accept the latter but not the former.  If `noteObject` has a defined class that doesn't usually respond to `footer`, it will give a warning, but still compile and run.  In these cases, it is your responsibility to guarantee that the method will indeed exist when needed, and therefore that the method call won't crash at run time.

Answer (score 1):

`NSObject` doesn't have any property named `footer`, which is why the compiler is complaining. Casting an id back to an `NSObject` doesn't help. If you know the object is always going to be some custom object you've created, you can cast back to that and then call footer and the compiler won't complain. It's best to actually check tho. See the example below (for the example, I named the class that has the `footer` property `ViewWithFooter`, so rename appropriately):

```
- (void)handleUnpresent:(NSNotification*)note
{
  ViewWithFooter view = (ViewWithFooter*)[note object];
  NSParameterAssert([view isKindOfClass:[ViewWithFooter class]]);
  UIView* footer = [view footer];
  // Do something with the footer...
  NSLog(@"Footer: %@", footer);
}
```

If you have a bunch of unrelated classes (i.e., not in the same class hierarchy) that all present a `footer` property, you'd be best served creating a protocol with the required `footer` property and casting the object to the protocol in the code example above and asserting it responds to the `-footer` selector.

Here's an example using the protocol:

```
@protocol ViewWithFooter <NSObject>

- (UIView*)footer; // this could also be a readonly property, or whatever

@end

- (void)handleUnpresent:(NSNotification*)note
{
  id<ViewWithFooter> view = (id<ViewWithFooter>)[note object];
  NSParameterAssert([view respondsToSelector:@selector(footer)]);
  UIView* footer = [view footer];
  // Do something with the footer...
  NSLog(@"Footer: %@", footer);
}
```

Comment: for curiosity sake, is there any way to bypass using a class by using something like `((id *)note.object).footer` in a way that the compiler won't be mad?

Comment: Bypass?  Properties require explicit declaration.  (also, to be pedantic, id is already a pointer).

Comment: You could use `[[note object] performSelector:@selector(footer)]`.  The compiler won't complain about this but if `footer` is not implemented you'll get the usual `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  If you wrap the call to `performSelector` in a `respondsToSelector` conditional you'll be covered.

Comment: @Jackson Just make a protocol and cast it to that. I'll add the protocol example to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the `object` passed in the notification may be one of a number of classes and you don't want to cast the object to a specific class you can use `performSelector:` to call the `footer` method on the object.  If you wrap this call with a `respondsToSelector:` you'll avoid an exception if the object turns out not to have a `footer` method.

```
-(void)handleUnpresent:(NSNotification *)note;
{
    if ([[note object] respondsToSelector:@selector(footer)]) {
        NSString *footer = [[note object] performSelector:@selector(footer)];

        NSLog(@"%@", footer);
    }
}
```

Using `performSelector` will stop the compiler complaining that the method "'footer' not found on object of type 'id'."